# Don't understand composition in Go

Tags: struct, interface, go, composition

In the example below I've embedded `http.ResponseWriter` into my own struct called `Response`. I've also added an extra field called `Status`. Why can't I access that field from inside my `root` handler function?

When I print out the type of `w` in my root handler function it says it's of type `main.Response` which seems correct and when I print out the values of the struct I can see that `Status` is there. Why can't I access by going `w.Status`?

This is the contents of stdout:

```
main.Response
{ResponseWriter:0xc2080440a0 Status:0}
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "net/http"
)

type Response struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    Status int
}

func (r Response) WriteHeader(n int) {
    r.Status = n
    r.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(n)
}

func middleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        resp := Response{ResponseWriter: w}

        h.ServeHTTP(resp, r)
    })
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("root"))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(w))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", w)
    fmt.Println(w.Status) // <--- This causes an error.
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", middleware(http.HandlerFunc(root)))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w` is a variable of type `http.ResponseWriter`. `ResponseWriter` does not have a field or method `Status`, only your `Response` type.

`http.ResponseWriter` is an interface type, and since your `Response` type implements it (because it embeds `ResponseWriter`), the `w` variable may hold a value of dynamic type `Response` (and in your case it does).

But to access the `Response.Status` field, you have to convert it to a value of type `Response`. For that use [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
if resp, ok := w.(Response); ok {
    // resp is of type Response, you can access its Status field
    fmt.Println(resp.Status) // <--- properly prints status
}
```